# Existe a função de módulo de um número em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, matemática

Exemplo : modulo de -1 (|-1| = 1). Já fiz algumas pesquisas na internet mas tudo que acho é o modulo da divisão (%). Estou tentando driblar a forma comum de passar um número negativo para um positivo, que seria fazer uma verificação para ver se o número é negativo ou não antes de multiplicar por -1.

Comment: Valor absoluto (abs): https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.math.abs?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Não havia me lembrado do método abs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pra mim módulo em programação sempre foi o que este operador faz, então a resto da descrição fica contraditório, mas o que descreveu parece ser que quer pegar o valor sem sinal, então seria o método [`Abs()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.abs?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Como ele pega o valor absoluto, ou seja, sem sinal, não importa se ele é positivo ou negativo o resultado dele será um positivo. Este método faz exatamente a verificação se é positivo ou não antes de mudar o sinal e faz a troca de sinal (não usa nem `if`, nem multiplicação que são ineficientes, pode [ver o código fonte](https://source.dot.net/#System.Runtime.Numerics/System/Numerics/NumericsHelpers.cs,f3594fa4fe1fd5e6)).

```
Math.Abs(-1) //resulta em 1
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/Abs.cs).

Comment: Obrigado não me lembrava da função desta função.

Comment: onde fica o código do Abs para double? Ou só tem pra inteiros?

Comment: @jsbueno que eu saiba não está disponível em C#, é feito pela biblioteca C padrão do sistema operacional já que é mais complexo fazer isso e deve ter algum macete, por isso preferiram delegar.

Comment: Na verdade o problema deve ser regional, talvez você tenha aprendido na escola com o nome _valor absoluto_, eu aprendi como _módulo_ mesmo.. Só descobri que também é chamado de valor absoluto quando comecei a programar. Também vi que é chamado de _valor absoluto_ e também de _módulo_ em Portugal.

Comment: Só descobri que Módulo também pode ser chamado de Valor abosluto....agora. Já no inglês só existe "absolute value" mesmo.

Comment: @jsbueno você pode usar o `static double Abs(double n) => n > 0 ? n : n * -1;`.

Comment: Em matemática, em português do brasil, usamos "módulo", mesmo. E o "modulo" em inglês, que existe nas linguagens de programação é "resto".

Comment: Quanto à minha pergunta, e u só queria ver se tinha alguma coisa "ixperta" pra ponto flutuante, e confirmar se tem essa dispairdade de API de Integer pra Float mesmo. Eu não programo em C#.

Comment: @jsbueno a API não, mas a implementação é bem diferente e até dependente da plataforma, então o resultado pode variar (ainda que eu acho que não deveria).